# Chromeで印刷したとき、Tableの行高さがおかしくなる

Tags: css, html, google-chrome

Tableタグで構成された表をChromeで印刷すると、tdの高さがランダムに倍になってしまいます。

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>名前</td>
        <td>住所</td>
        <td>電話番号</td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

上記のようなシンプルなtableで構成されています。
Chromeの印刷プレビューで、
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
のように行が倍の高さになる箇所が発生し、そのまま印刷されてしまいます。
tdに高さを与えても効果がありませんでした。

上記のような症状の解決法をご存知でしょうか？
宜しくお願いします。

Comment: 英語版SOでも類似質問"[strange cell height in table when printing in chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15567919/)", "[Chrome print tables, some rows have a random height?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17412324/)"が挙っていました。

Comment: trまたは、tdのテーブルの高さはどういった方法(プロパティ)で記述していますか？

Comment: @名も無いWEB屋 ありがとうございます。
tdに対して、height,line-heightを与えています。
どんな数値を入れても行が倍になってしまう箇所が発生しています。